# Entity Framework Core 3.0 different results when using DbSet vs.DbQuery and FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

If I call the same code:

> `return _context.dtoCostCodes <br> .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT distinct '' as
>   ID, CostCode, BusinessUnitID from  CostCodes where IsActive = 1 and
>   BusinessUnitID = '{id}'").ToList();`

First with my DBContext set as

> `public DbQuery<DTO.dtoCostCode> dtoCostCodes { get; set; }`

and then with:

> `public DbSet<DTO.dtoCostCode> dtoCostCodes { get; set; }`

The DbQuery gives me the correct results in both record count and data.  If I use DbSet, it gives me the correct record count, but the first row is duplicated over and over again.

Any idea to the cause of this behavior?

My concern is that in .net Core 3.0 DbQuery is obsolete and I'll run into different issues down the line.  We just upgraded from 2.2 where I was able to use

```
            select new dtoCostCode
        {
            ID = c.ID,
            JDECostCode = c.JDECostCode,
            BusinessUnitID = c.BusinessUnitID
        }).Where(cc => cc.BusinessUnitID == id).GroupBy(cc => cc.JDECostCode).Select(y => y.First()).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

But it is no longer supported in 3.0

Comment: Where did you learn its no longer supported? It looks like raw SQL still is. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql  You should also be able to view the actual sql query being created under the Output window ( I think), when debugging. You might just need to readjust your Linq statement base on what the query actaully looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be using FromSqlInterpolated rather than FromSqlRaw, as you are using an interpolated string.

Regarding why your old code doesn't work, post up the rest of the statement as you're only showing the projection.

Efcore 3 changed the way queries are executed meaning there are some parts of complex queries you may need to do manually.